# Automation vs Instrumentation Testing in Android

Tags: android, automation

android automation developers use selenium to create and validate flows in the app. However, can't we automate the app by developing Instrumentation Tests? What benefits do we gain from using selenium as opposed to just developing an Instrumentation Test for each activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both accomplish the same thing